Conditional mean of a Gaussian Process converges to zero. How to choose the Kernel?
I'm seeking insights on a phenomenon I observed while applying a Gaussian Process (GP) to the function $\sin(x^2)$ over the interval $x \in [-10, 10]$. This question is a follow up of the discussion in Why is the mean function in Gaussian Process uninteresting?
My GP model uses a zero mean and an RBF kernel with a fixed length scale. The training dataset consists of 50 evenly spaced points, starting from $x = -10$. While the GP effectively captures the underlying function within the range of the training data, generating an accurate conditional mean, I've noticed a bad behavior when extrapolating.
As soon as the GP starts making predictions beyond the training range, the conditional mean quickly reverts to zero – aligning with the GP's prior mean. This confounds me, as the training data evidently suggests a periodic nature of the function with an amplitude fluctuating between $[-1, 1]$. I expected the conditional mean to mirror this periodicity and amplitude, especially based on the training evidence.
Can someone explain why the GP's conditional mean deviates from the observed periodicity during extrapolation, despite the evidence provided by the training points?
I understand that the RBF kernel decays exponentially as we go away from the training point, and a better choice would be to use a period kernel. But what if we don't know that the underlying function is periodic?
Maybe the question here is: what is the correct procedure to select a specific kernel when fitting a gaussian process? Do we maximise the marginalized likelihood for each kernel with respect to their parameter, and we pick the kernel that results into the biggest marginalized likelihood?
In the following plot, the blue points are the values of the true function $sin(x^2)$ and the green points are the observations in the training set. The red line is the conditional mean and the gray bands are the $2\sigma$ confidence level. I have restricted the x-axis from -10 to -5.

I also attach the python code to reproduce this figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fit(X:np.array, Y:np.array, l:float, obs:np.array, kernel):
    obs_y = Y[obs]
    test_X = np.delete(np.array([i for i in range(len(X))]), obs)
    
    K = kernel(l)
    kernel_obs = K[obs][:,obs]
    kernel_obs_test = K[obs][:,test_X]
    kernel_test_obs = K[test_X][:,obs]
    kernel_test = K[test_X][:,test_X]
    
    conditional_mean = kernel_test_obs @ np.linalg.inv(kernel_obs) @ obs_y
    conditional_cov = kernel_test - kernel_test_obs @ np.linalg.inv(kernel_obs) @ kernel_obs_test 
    
    functions = np.random.multivariate_normal(conditional_mean, conditional_cov,3000)
    mean = functions.mean(axis=0)
    upperband = functions.mean(axis=0) + 2*functions.std(axis=0)
    lowerband = functions.mean(axis=0) - 2*functions.std(axis=0)
    
    return test_X, mean, upperband, lowerband


X = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

y = np.sin(X**2) 

DX = np.array([[X[i] - X[j] for j in range(len(X))] for i in range(len(X))]) # Compute the distance matrix
kernel = lambda l: np.exp(-0.5*DX ** 2/l**2) # This is the RBF kernel

np.random.seed(14)
obs = np.arange(0, 200, 4)
obs_X = X[obs]
obs_y = y[obs]

x, mean, upperband, lowerband = fit(X, y, 0.05, obs, kernel)
plt.fill_between(X[x], upperband, lowerband, color='gray', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(obs_X, obs_y, 'g+', markersize=20)
plt.plot(X,y, 'b+')
plt.plot(X[x], mean, 'r')
plt.xlim(-10,-5)


What property of a Gaussian process suggests it ought to do any better than this at extrapolation?  It's certainly not even stationary, which puts you at a huge disadvantage right at the outset.

@whuber Well.. I don’t expect predictions from GP to be valid all the way to infinity. I would expect that locally the non-stationarity of the function doesn’t play role. In other words, I am surprised the mean of the prediction converges to zero very quickly when I fit the process on a region where the function’s non-stationarity is barely clear. It is a matter of scales.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/380218/298651 seems related, although it deals more with the trend aspect and not thr covariance aspect

Re "matter of scales:" exactly.  What is the effective range of your kernel?  Any extrapolation beyond its range is essentially going to be an arithmetic mean.  And with long-range kernels, what happens depends on the dimension of the data (I haven't studied 1D data except as toy examples), but I would expect the well-known "screening effect" to cause the extrapolation rapidly to approach a weighted mean of a small amount of data closest to the extrapolation region (with the weights depending on the weight of decay of the kernel's tails).

@whuber yes, the kernel decays very fast because the effective range is 0.05 units, but that's the optimal length derived from maximization of the marginal likelihood, it is not chosen by hand.
Here's my feeling: I am not applying a GP in a suitable way for the problem at hand. Or the RBF kernel is not the right kernel to use. Can it be? Or are you telling me that there is no way to make better predictions with a GP?

In this case you would need a different method, one that is capable of adjusting the square-root spacing between the peaks and detecting the resulting seasonality.
